# Preventing SQL deadlocks when database is updated by two different processes

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

We have a system with two different processes that update the same sql server tables.    One process has high transaction volume and is initiated by a scheduled task that runs 24 X 7.   The other is a low transaction volume process that is initiated by user volume.   The second process database transactions are frequently being killed because of deadlocks.    I'm not sure how to fix this.   Ideally, I would want the user instantiated transactions to have priority and for the scheduled task transactions to essentially wait until the database was free.

Comment: I vaguely know about https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866(v=sql.110).aspx Also in sql server 2014 you can set the transaction priority

Comment: You can assign deadlock priority to the session: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186736.aspx but be careful with that, since then it will definitely kill the ones with lower priority first, regardless of how much work they have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for us, the solution was to change the isolation level from Read Committed to Read Comitted Snapshot.   What this does is cause all Selects to snapshot the table its reading before doing the select.   It thus prevents selects from colliding with each other causing the deadlock   An alternative would have been to use (NOLOCK) query hints on all select statements.   However, we have a lot of sql and we were looking at rewriting a lot of code.   Changing the isolation level was easy and quick and did not require a lot of regression testing.

Comment: The alternative to using (NOLOCK) hint on every table is just use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITED` once at the start... but yes SNAPSHOT isolation is a far superior solution.